# Word VBA: How to Fix FOR EACH loop to add bookmark to each sentence?

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-word, bookmarks

Within a Word docx: I'm trying to add a bookmark to each sentence. For example, at first sentence would be bookmark "bmarkpg01" and second sentence would be bookmark ""bmarkpg01ln01col01"". My code adds only one bookmark to first sentence and doesn't loop through to end of document.

I've tried a for each loop to attempt each sent in sentences and each bmark in bookmark.

```
Sub tryAddBmarkatSentence()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim bmark As Bookmark

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each MySent In ActiveDocument.Sentences
    For Each bmark In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="pmark" & bmark.Range.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber), Range:=myRange 'bmark name would have added info of page, line, and col number. here as example is pagenumber.

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

EXPECTED RESULT: Within entire document, each sentence has a corresponding bookmark and bookmark name ("bmarkpg01ln01col01", "bmarkpg01ln02col10", etc.)

ACTUAL RESULTS: only one bookmark is added to the first sentence of the document.

Comment: hi. u have a double Each, so, it only add a bookmark if a sentence and a bookmark exists. u must get only the sentences and then add the bookmark

Comment: Thanks, Luis. So how would that update the above code?

Comment: You should be aware that Word doesn't really understand sentences so the results you get may be not what you are expecting. Paragraphs yes, sentences no.

Comment: Great point. Didn't think about the names of sentences. Might try to create a bookmark for each paragraph and then try another strategy. The trustee goal is to find overlapping text as granular as possible without overloading system resources

Comment: Blasted android autocorrect. *Issues with sentences. **Ultimate goal

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me, as far as the requirements in the question go.

Please remember to put `Option Explicit` at the top of a code page. This will force you to declare ("Dim") variables, but will also save time and trouble as it will prevent typos and warn you of other problems.

A `Sentence` in Word returns a `Range` object, so the code below delares `MySent As Range`. This provides the target `Range` for the `Bookmarks.Add` method.

If you won't be doing anything else with the bookmark, it's not strictly necessary to `Set bkm =` when adding the bookmark. I left it in since it is declared in the code in the question.

It's not necessary to loop the collection of bookmarks - espeicially since there aren't any - they're being added.

I've added some code for naming the bookmarks, as well.

```
Sub tryAddBmarkatSentence()
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim MySent As Word.Range
    Dim bmark As Bookmark

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    For Each MySent In doc.Sentences
        Set bmark = doc.Bookmarks.Add(Name:="bmark" & _
        MySent.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber) & "_" &_
        MySent.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber) & "_" & _
        MySent.Information(wdFirstCharacterColumnNumber), Range:=MySent)
        'bmark name would have added info of page, line, and col number. here as example is pagenumber.
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

u can try like this

```
Sub tryAddBmarkatSentence()
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim bmark As Bookmark

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each MySent In ActiveDocument.Sentences

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add ... and the rest of the code.
        //i dont know how you define witch bookmark is to asign to that sentence

Next

End Sub
```